# Changing ImageView Content with Getting ID

Tags: java, android, import, dynamic-programming, dynamic-content

ID's and states:

[image: ID's and states]

When i try to change state of any item:

[image: When i try to change state of any item]

i was trying to select items from database and getting theirs ID for changing imageview. But it gets always last items value and that causes to make everything just like the last one.

Here is the code at below:

```
`package orhanapp.sqlapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Context;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;


public class Rooms extends Activity {

    Temiz temizz=new Temiz();

    ConnectionClass connectionClass;
    String z;
    EditText edtId, edtNo;
    TextView text,textviewisim;
    ProgressBar pbbar;
    ListView lstpro;
    String proid;
    ImageView img;

    Temiz temiz=new Temiz();
    String s,s1,s2,s3;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rooms);


        connectionClass = new ConnectionClass();
        edtId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtId);
        edtNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtNo);

        text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("veri"));

        textviewisim=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textviewisim);
        textviewisim.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("veriisim"));

        pbbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pbbar);
        pbbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        lstpro = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstproducts);
        proid = "";




        Rooms.FillList fillList = new Rooms.FillList();
        fillList.execute("");


    }



    public class FillList extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        String z = "";

        List<Map<String, String>> prolist  = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            pbbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }




        @Override


        protected void onPostExecute (String r){

            pbbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(Rooms.this, r, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            String[] from = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
            int[] views = {R.id.lblproid, R.id.lblproname, R.id.lblId, R.id.lblState};
            final SimpleAdapter Temiz = new SimpleAdapter(Rooms.this,
                    prolist, R.layout.activity_temiz, from,
                    views);

            final SimpleAdapter Dolu = new SimpleAdapter(Rooms.this,
                    prolist, R.layout.activity_dolu, from,
                    views);

            final SimpleAdapter Kirli = new SimpleAdapter(Rooms.this,
                    prolist, R.layout.activity_kirli, from,
                    views);

            final SimpleAdapter Arizali = new SimpleAdapter(Rooms.this,
                    prolist, R.layout.activity_arizali, from,
                    views);




            if (s.startsWith("0")) {

                lstpro.setAdapter(Temiz);

            } else if (s.startsWith("1")) {

                lstpro.setAdapter(Dolu);

            } else if (s.startsWith("2")) {

                lstpro.setAdapter(Kirli);

            } else if (s.startsWith("3")) {

                lstpro.setAdapter(Arizali);
            }




            lstpro.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                        int arg2, long arg3) {  

                    HashMap<String, Object> obj = (HashMap<String, Object>) Temiz
                            .getItem(arg2);

                    proid = (String) obj.get("A");
                    String proname = (String) obj.get("B");
                    String prodesc = (String) obj.get("C");
                    String state = (String) obj.get("D");
                    edtId.setText(prodesc);
                    edtNo.setText(proname);



                    HashMap<String, Object> obj1 = (HashMap<String, Object>) Dolu
                            .getItem(arg2);

                    proid = (String) obj.get("A");
                    String proname1 = (String) obj.get("B");
                    String prodesc1 = (String) obj.get("C");
                    String state1 = (String) obj.get("D");
                    edtId.setText(prodesc1);
                    edtNo.setText(proname1);


                    HashMap<String, Object> obj2 = (HashMap<String, Object>) Kirli
                            .getItem(arg2);

                    proid = (String) obj.get("A");
                    String proname2 = (String) obj.get("B");
                    String prodesc2 = (String) obj.get("C");
                    String state2 = (String) obj.get("D");
                    edtId.setText(prodesc2);
                    edtNo.setText(proname2);

                    HashMap<String, Object> obj3 = (HashMap<String, Object>) Arizali
                            .getItem(arg2);

                    proid = (String) obj.get("A");
                    String proname3 = (String) obj.get("B");
                    String prodesc3 = (String) obj.get("C");
                    String state3 = (String) obj.get("D");
                    edtId.setText(prodesc3);
                    edtNo.setText(proname3);


                    Intent intent = new Intent(Rooms.this, StateRoom.class);
                    intent.putExtra("veri2", edtId.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("veriOdano", edtNo.getText().toString());
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });

        }

        String id=text.getText().toString();

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {
                Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
                if (con == null) {
                    z = "Error in connection with SQL server";
                } else {

                    String query = "select * from deneme2 where Id="+id+"";
                    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
                    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

                    ArrayList<String> data1 = new ArrayList<String>();

                    while (rs.next()) {


                        Map<String, String> datanum = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        datanum.put("A", rs.getString("Id"));
                        datanum.put("B", rs.getString("OdaNo"));
                        datanum.put("C", rs.getString("bolId"));
                        datanum.put("D", rs.getString("Durum"));
                        prolist.add(datanum);


                        s = datanum.get("D");



                    }

                    z = "Success";
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                z = "Error retrieving data from table";

            }

            return z;
        }


    }



}`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (rs.next() && rs.first()) {


                        Map<String, String> datanum = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        datanum.put("A", rs.getString("Id"));
                        datanum.put("B", rs.getString("OdaNo"));
                        datanum.put("C", rs.getString("bolId"));
                        datanum.put("D", rs.getString("Durum"));
                        prolist.add(datanum);


                        s = datanum.get("D");



                    }
```

Replace this code with existing

Comment: thanks for the feedback but when i run that code i got an error as 'App has stopped'.